# Flutter AndroidManifest.xml exists but gradle says it doesnt

Tags: flutter

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34

This Android Gradle plugin (7.3.0) was tested up to compileSdk = 33

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34
> Task :generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Error while evaluating property 'applicationId' of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'applicationId'.
      > Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.
         > Manifest file does not exist: C:\Users\User\Desktop\flutter\MinamotoApp2\MinamotoApp\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

There is a AndroidManifest.xml file that has no error as I checked with ChatGPT.
I've done everything I could I don't know why it still says AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist even though it does. it is not hidden and it is not read only.

I tried flutter pub upgrade, flutter upgrade, and ./gradlew clean it still says that AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist.